# Cannot read property 'injector' of null in TestBed.createComponent when running tests in angular2 and jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angular, browserify, karma-jasmine

When running a simple test with karma and browserify my test crashes inside TestBed.createComponent() function.

Here is the beforeEach which is crashing:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { AboutPage } from './about'


beforeEach(() => {

    // refine the test module by declaring the test component
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AboutPage ],
    });

    // create component and test fixture
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutPage);

    // get test component from the fixture
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
```

And the error received:

```
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) About component should display original title FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null
        at TestBed._createCompilerAndModule (/var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:834:0 <- /var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/57bca79162ed1bcbdc3d746a5d9211d7.browserify:3968:48)
        at TestBed._initIfNeeded (/var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:800:0 <- /var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/57bca79162ed1bcbdc3d746a5d9211d7.browserify:3934:43)
        at TestBed.createComponent (/var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:884:0 <- /var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/57bca79162ed1bcbdc3d746a5d9211d7.browserify:4018:18)
        at Function.TestBed.createComponent (/var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:714:0 <- /var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/57bca79162ed1bcbdc3d746a5d9211d7.browserify:3848:33)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/src/pages/about/about.spec.ts:24:22 <- /var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/57bca79162ed1bcbdc3d746a5d9211d7.browserify:50004:37)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:203:28)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:72:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:202:34)
        at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:96:43)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:91:50)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/src/pages/about/about.spec.ts:33:12 <- /var/folders/by/05whlcq9247dyx85bd0l183w0000gn/T/57bca79162ed1bcbdc3d746a5d9211d7.browserify:50010:16)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:203:28)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:72:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:202:34)
        at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:96:43)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:91:50)
        at ZoneQueueRunner.jasmine.QueueRunner.ZoneQueueRunner.execute (node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:119:42)
```

And here's the code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  helloText: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  sayHello(){
    this.helloText = "hello";
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

- **Operating system:** osx 10.11.6
- **Angular version:** 2.0.1
  "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
  "browserify": "13.1.0"
- **Node:** `node --version` =   v6.7.0

Comment: If `AboutPage` has HTML and CSS, have you tried to resolve `TestBed.compileComponents` before trying to create one?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, is a normal angular2 component with a selector and a templateUrl (I'll add the code in the question). What do you mean by reasolving `TestBed.compileComponents?`

Comment: I mean call that method and resolve the promise it returns (`TestBed.compileComponents().then(...)`). See e.g. https://github.com/textbook/known-for-web/blob/master/src/app/actor/actor.component.spec.ts#L54

Comment: Yes, I've tried it but is not working ... Same `TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you forgot to init platform:

```
import { 
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule, 
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting 
} 
from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

See also **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/N8ydS9vpwCfZmVBIExBt?p=preview)**

Comment: When I add this I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined.

It's coming from __extends on MockDirectiveResolver.